# DevTools was disconnected from the page

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

У меня выскакивает ошибка "**DevTools was disconnected from the page**" когда я пытаюсь зайти в инструменты разработчика (F12). Помогите понять и решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Отвечаю на собственный вопрос. (Нашёл почему)
Подобная вещь случается, если в коде случается бесконечный цикл. Собственно, его удаление исправит проблему "DevTools was disconnected from the page".